# Call PHP page with Swift

Tags: swift

I'm writing code in Swift on Xcode. My application have to launch a PHP page. The link is something like: "http://mypage.php?param=Hello"
The PHP page works perfectly, in fact "Hello" is stored in my db.

How can I implement this function in my App?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Explain what you mean by "launch a PHP page".  Do you want to display this page in your app or read the data from that page and do something with it?

Comment: Can you add some code where you are stuck?

Comment: I want to send data to my PHP page, like in the example "Hello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, how you can do an HTTP GET request using Swift:

```
let param = NSURLQueryItem(name: "param", value: "Hello")

let urlComponents = NSURLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "http";
urlComponents.host = "mypage.com";
urlComponents.path = "/phpfile.php";
urlComponents.queryItems = [param]

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(urlComponents.URL!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if error != nil
    {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
})

task.resume()
```

You can create more query parameters by defining more *NSURLQueryItem*s and adding them to *urlComponents.queryItems*. Assuming that your php code will return some kinds of status response, you can check that in the *responseString*.